# Why can't I initialize a QThread in a member function of class?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyside

Here is the code:

```
##########################################################
######## Version 1 (works)
##########################################################
#!/usr/bin/env python3


from ui.qthreadtest import Ui_QthreadTest
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import time

class Md(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.prcsbtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Process")
        self.prcsedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.prcsedit)
        layout.addWidget(self.prcsbtn)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.prcsbtn.clicked.connect(self.work)

        self.wt = Worker()

    def work(self):
        self.wt.start()
        # the DirectConnection option demands the slot to be triggered immediately
        self.wt.workFinished.connect(self.changeText, QtCore.Qt.DirectConnection)

    def changeText(self):
        self.prcsedit.setText("Work finished!")

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    workFinished = QtCore.Signal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.workFinished.emit()

import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
md = Md()
md.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())


##########################################################
######## Version 2 (doesn't work)    
##########################################################

#!/usr/bin/env python3


from ui.qthreadtest import Ui_QthreadTest
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import time

class Md(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.prcsbtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Process")
        self.prcsedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.prcsedit)
        layout.addWidget(self.prcsbtn)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.prcsbtn.clicked.connect(self.work)


    def work(self):
        # the worker thread initialized in a member function won't work.
        wt = Worker()
        wt.start()
        # the DirectConnection option demands the slot to be triggered immediately
        wt.workFinished.connect(self.changeText, QtCore.Qt.DirectConnection)

    def changeText(self):
        self.prcsedit.setText("Work finished!")

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    workFinished = QtCore.Signal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.workFinished.emit()

import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
md = Md()
md.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Version 1 works ok, version 2 gives this error (while crushing instantly when the Process button is pressed):

```
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running

Process finished with exit code 139
```

Comment: The error message could hardly have made things more obvious, especially since the only real difference between the two examples is that one keeps a reference to the worker thread, whilst the other one doesn't. Also, you should be aware that using a [direct connection for the signal is not safe](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because unlike `threading.Thread` objects, `QThread` objects get destroyed as soon as they go out of scope. In your example, `wt` goes out of scope when `work` ends, so the object gets destroyed. To avoid this, you'll need to keep a lasting reference to `wt`. One way to do this would be to make it an instance variable:

```
def work(self):
    self.wt = Worker()
    self.wt.start()
    # the DirectConnection option demands the slot to be triggered immediately
    self.wt.workFinished.connect(self.changeText, QtCore.Qt.DirectConnection)
```